# Lookup and concatenate unique multiple values into one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the following table

| Type | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | Banana |
| Veg | Carrot |
| Fruit | Mango |
| Fruit | Banana |
| Veg | Lettuce |
| Fruit | Banana |
| Fruit | Apples |
| Fruit | Mango |

I want to look up the `Type`, in this case `Fruit` and return into a single cell, a list of unique `Item`'s. For example, looking on up `Fruit` would return `Banana; Mango; Apples`. As you can see,    we did not add the duplicate `Banana`'s and `Mango`'s

I have tried the following, where `D2` cell contains the type `Fruit`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(D2=A2:A9, B2:B9, ""))
```

I want to do this in pure excel, no VBA

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Excel as part of the Office 365 package, you can achieve this using unique & filter (screenshot / [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98B1Ac5drHME9cFcI?e=xaIT06) link refer):

```
=TextJoin(",",True,UNIQUE(FILTER(C5:C12,B5:B12=F4)))
```

[image: Screenshot]

*(modify True/False if you want blanks to appear; customize delimiter as desired)*